# 1 divided by very large number return 0, C

Tags: c, double, division, gaussian

i decided to post this question because i'm not sure why i'm getting this result. I researched in this site and others finding no solution. Sorry if i'm violating this websites rules but remember, i'm new.
This is the code of the function written in C that is returning the unexpected result:

```
double gauss (double average, double variance, int data)
    {
    double model,power;
    power = ((((data-average)*(data-average))/(2*variance))*(1));
    model = (pow(E,(int)power));
    return 1.0/model;
    }
```

i don't know if i should post the rest of my code but i will if you want to, i just wanted to keep the post short. The issue is occuring with 1.0/model because model is a very big number.

Comment: At the least, it would help if you could show what the value of `model` is at the point of division. Also, have you tried using `long double`?

Comment: What value has `power`? Most likely, `model = pow(E,(int)power);` overflows and `model` becomes infinity. If the representation of `double`s is, as it most likely is, IEEE754, no reciprocal of a finite value is 0.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson actually i just changed my printf("%lf", gauss(double average, double variance, int data) to printf("%e", gauss(double average, double variance, int data)) and now it's showing a result diferent to 0.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  People often think a value is zero just because `printf` output '0'.

Comment: @paddy so should i always use scientific notation to avoid these kind of scenarios? is it a good practice?

Comment: You might try `pow(1.0/E, (int)power)` instead.

Comment: or just `pow(E, -(int)power)`

Comment: @GilLázaro It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Obviously in this case, you don't want `printf` to round tiny values to zero.  But sometimes you do.  In that case, scientific notation makes sense.  You can use the `%g` specifier if you want the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

C doubles have limited precision, so if you divide 1.0 by a very large double, the precision error will net you 0 (effectively, the actual answer is so close to zero that the precision error will round to zero).

You could try to use `long double` for more precision, but I think you would be better off using an arbitrary precision library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: I think Daniel Fischer is closer to the truth.

Answer (score 0):

The value of power must be tending towards infinity as it gives the result 0. As suggested by @jh314, try long double for all variables. It will increase the range of your **model** variable & may be give any accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was not using scientific notation to print the number, which led me to believe the actual value was zero.